# amazon s3+paperclip - AWS::S3::NoSuchBucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I’ve used Uploadify and paperclip in Rails3 and I’m getting this error -

AWS::S3::NoSuchBucket (The specified bucket does not exist):

app/controllers/cards_controller.rb:79:in `create'

app/controllers/cards_controller.rb:78:in `create'

app/middleware/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:16:in `call'

My s3.yml file is

————————————————–

development:
bucket: bucket-dev
access_key_id: ###
secret_access_key: ###
test:
bucket: bucket-test
access_key_id: ###
secret_access_key: ###
production:
bucket: bucket-pro
access_key_id:###
secret_access_key: ###

————————————————–

and the model has -

————————————————–

has_attached_file :photo,

:storage => :s3,

:s3_credentials => “#{::Rails.root.to_s}/config/s3.yml”,

:path => “/:style/:filename”,

:styles => {:medium => “300×300>”,:thumb => “100×100>”}

————————————————–

Comment: I've been seeing these errors as well, but intermittently and with buckets in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safalmj, do you have buckets created on S3 called 'bucket-test' and 'bucket-pro'? If not, sign into the AWS Console and create them first.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. I was just having this very same issue. Then I read something about Paperclip creating buckets where they don't exist. I appended a 1 to the end of my already created bucket name, and all of a sudden it worked. I think it might have something to do with the other end. Try setting the bucket name to something other than the one you've probably already created... Highly counter intuitive...

Comment: The problem with renaming buckets is that at some point you start having the same issue with the new bucket name, so this is not a solution for a production system.